# Syntax Error: unexpected Identifier in node js callback function

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function abc(){
    console.log("Delieverd food order: ",orderNumber);
}

function placeOrder(orderNumber){
    console.log("Customer: ", orderNumber);
    cookAndDeliverFood(abc);
}

fucntion cookAndDeliverFood(callback){
    setTimeout(callback,5000);
}

//Simulate users webrequests

placeOrder(1);

placeOrder(2);

placeOrder(3);

placeOrder(4);

placeOrder(5);
```

This is giving me syntax error. Can anyone explain the reason?

Comment: `fucntion` !== `function`

Comment: `orderNumber` is not in scope in `abc`. It will be `undefined`.

Comment: `console.log("Customer: ", orderNumber);` have comma in it. Please replace it with plus (+).

Comment: @Shubham `console.log` prints all of its parameters as space-separated strings, so alternatively they could just remove the space after the colon.

Comment: `fucntion cookAndDeliverFood()` should be `function cookAndDeliverFood`. it may be a typo.

Comment: @DeepKakkar It's great to edit code for formatting, but don't fix syntax errors which are relevant to fixing the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Running your code, I get this error:

```
fucntion cookAndDeliverFood(callback)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

You have misspelled the keyword `function`.

That is not the only problem with the code. Function `abc()` tries to use the identifier `orderNumber` but, the way this code is written, `orderNumber` is out of scope there. But the misspelling of `function` is the immediate problem you are facing and the reason you are getting a `SyntaxError`.